# Gerar um arquivo excel a partir de um data grid C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, interop

Estou tentando gerar um arquivo excel a partir de um datagrid, e isso esta gerando o seguinte erro:
[image: ERRO]

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in EletronicTaxNotes.exe

Additional information: Não é possível converter o objeto COM do tipo 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' na interface tipo 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. Esta operação falhou porque a chamada de QueryInterface no componente COM para a interface com IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' falhou devido ao seguinte erro: Erro ao carregar a biblioteca/DLL de tipo. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

```
private void ExportarExcel2()
{
  // Creating a Excel object. 
        Excel._Application excel = new Excel.Application();

        if (excel == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!"); return;
        }

        Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        try
        {
            Excel._Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

            worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";

            worksheet.Cells[1, 0] = "Codigo";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Descrição";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Fornecedor";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Quantidade";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Preço";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Preço Total";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Ncm";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Nota";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 8] = "DataDocumento";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Tipo";

            // Passa as celulas do DataGridView para a Pasta do Excel
            for (var i = 0; i <= gridItens.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = j <= 2 ? gridItens[j, i] : gridNotas[j, i];
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user. 
            var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Filter = @"Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 2
            };

            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show(@"Export Successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            excel.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Segui as seguintes sugestões, para que incluísse as devidas referências:

[What reference do I need to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net)

[Cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986323/cannot-find-microsoft-office-interop-visual-studio)

[image: Instalação do pacote]

[image: Referências atualizadas1]

[image: Referências atualizadas2]

Também tentei outras sugestões, que consiste em excluir um registro duplicado que poderia estar causando o erro:

[Error Printing When Using Microssoft.office.interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936222/error-printing-when-using-microssoft-office-interop/42938079#42938079)

Mas o registro que esta dando erro não existe nos meus registros, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: Registros]

Da mesma forma as seguintes sugestões também não me ajudaram:

[Error accessing COM components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957595/error-accessing-com-components)

[Class not registered error when creating Excel workbook in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397506/class-not-registered-error-when-creating-excel-workbook-in-c-sharp)

Infelizmente nada disso surtiu efeito, sendo o resultado sempre o mesmo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou ficando sem opções para prosseguir. Imaginei que tal tarefa seria algo simples de ser feito. Alguém possui alguma outra sugestão de solução que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Poste os textos dos erros e cole os códigos aqui, **evite usar imagens**. Também atente para o uso das tags. Não é necessário usar a tag `visual-studio` em perguntas que não são sobre a IDE.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz as correções que sugeriu.

Answer (score 1):

Segue código que utilizo em minha aplicação:

referência Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

path: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

descrição:
Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library

Código:

```
 string ExcelFilePath = "Caminho do arquivo destino";
try
            {
                DataTable dt = //Obtém o Datatable

                int ColumnsCount = dt.Columns.Count;

                if (dt == null || (ColumnsCount) == 0)
                {
                    status = "Tabela de dados não foi definida.";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        status = "Nenhum Registro encontrado.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // load excel, and create a new workbook
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        Excel.Workbooks.Add();

                        // single worksheet
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;

                        object[] Header = new object[ColumnsCount];

                        // column headings               
                        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                            Header[i] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range HeaderRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, ColumnsCount]));
                        HeaderRange.Value = Header;
                        //HeaderRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
                        HeaderRange.Font.Bold = true;

                        // DataCells
                        int RowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                        object[,] Cells = new object[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];
                        maxp1 = RowsCount;
                        maxp2 = ColumnsCount;
                        int loop = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)
                        {
                            p1 = j + 1;
                            status = "Processando " + p1 + " / "+ RowsCount;

                            //backgroundWorkerExportExcel.ReportProgress(1);
                            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                            {
                                p2 = i + 1;
                                //status = "Entrando em linha " + j + " coluna " + i;
                                //backgroundWorkerExportExcel.ReportProgress(1);
                                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                                Cells[j, i] = dt.Rows[j][i];
                            }
                        }

                        Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[2, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount + 1, ColumnsCount])).Value = Cells;

                        // check fielpath
                        if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                                Excel.Quit();

                                status = "Exportado com sucesso!";
                                p1 = p2 = 0;
                                //backgroundWorkerExportExcel.ReportProgress(1);

                                //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved!");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ex.Message;
                                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n" + ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                        else    // no filepath is given
                        {
                            status = "Exportado com sucesso!";
                            Excel.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: O problema amigo é que nesse ponto:
Excel.Workbooks.Add();

A variável Excel esta sempre nulla, dessa forma não consigo dar add no Workbook.

Comment: você está instanciando o objeto dessa forma:  Excel._Application excel = new Excel.Application();

Comment: repare que você coloca _Application = new Application()

Comment: utilize assim: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Comment: Esta dessa forma por que estou usando um using:

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: sim, digo do _Application e Application, aparentemente são classes diferentes

Comment: Realmente não tinha reparado nisso, fiz a adequação e o problema persiste, pelo que entendi estava _application é um interface, no caso estava fazendo uma conversão explícita, mas mesmo que retire ela, essa conversão é feita na hora de criar o Workbooks, e é nesse momento que dá o erro. Até a mensagem fala sobre isso.

Comment: repare o trecho:  // load excel, and create a new workbook
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        Excel.Workbooks.Add();

                        // single worksheet
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;

Comment: coloque igual, sem o Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

Comment: Eu tinha notado essa diferença e feito essa alteração, mas ficou do mesmo jeito, então eu decidi tirar por completo qualquer chamada ao Workbook, mas mesmo assim na hora de instanciar o worksheet ele estoura uma exceção com a mesma mensagem de erro.

Comment: tenta trocar a versao do Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library , você esta usando a 16 e eu a 12

Comment: Finalmente consegui, apenas precisei instalar o office 2013, o que eu tinha era o 2016 e funcionou. Rovann muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: muito bom, parabens

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema após seguir todos os passo expostos na perguntar e instalar o office 2013, eu já possuía 2016, mas ao instalar a versão anterior o código funcionou perfeitamente.